# Export attachments to folder

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an Access table that I need to convert to SQL Server, but it has an attachment field. I am trying to export all the attachments to a specified folder and have each attachment files grouped by the primary key folder.

```
Function ExtractAttachment()
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset2
Dim rsA As DAO.Recordset2
Dim fld As DAO.Field
Dim savePath As String

    savePath = "\\MyFolder\" 'Folder path to save files

    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("tblEmpInfo") 'tblEmpInfo is table name
    Set fld = rst("EmpPhoto") 'EmpPhoto is Field name to table with attachment data type.

    Do While Not rst.EOF 'Loop through all records of table.
    Set rsA = fld.Value
        On Error Resume Next 'Omit errors if file already exist
        Do While Not rsA.EOF 'Loop through all attachment of single record
            rsA.Fields("FileData").SaveToFile savePath & rst.Fields(0) & "\" 'Save file to disk
            rsA.MoveNext
        Loop
    rst.MoveNext
    Loop

    rst.Close
    dbs.Close
Set fld = Nothing
Set rst = Nothing
Set dbs = Nothing
End Function
```

If I remove `& rst.Fields(0) & "\"` it creates all the files, but under the same folder and have no way to differentiate them.

How can I export the attachments by folder using the autonumber of the field (Primary Key)?

Comment: `If Dir(savePath & rst.Fields(0)) = "" Then MkDir savePath & rst.Fields(0)` or concatenate PK into file name.

Comment: @HansUp Nothing gets exported, but June7 code worked since it created the folder and then added the file.

Comment: @June7 that worked, but how can I add the PK to the file name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to make sure folder exists and if not, create it.
`If Dir(savePath & rst.Fields(0)) = "" Then MkDir savePath & rst.Fields(0)`

If you want to include record ID in exported file's name, specify in the destination path. Can still save to subfolders or just all into one folder.

```
rsA.Fields("FileData").SaveToFile savePath & rst.Fields(0) & "\" & rst.Fields(0) & rsA.Fields("FileName")
```